# Python 2 UTC time just print the hour minutes and seconds

Tags: python

In python 2 can you please tell me how to just print hours, minutes and seconds with UTC

Trying to avoid printing out the date 
Thanks

```
import datetime  
import pytz
T7 = datetime.datetime.utcnow() 
print(T7)
```

Comment: Use `print(T7.hour)` if you want print `hours`, other see [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.year); or use `strftime`  ,ref: [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

The code below will give you what you need.

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Problem solved, the examples I have been looking at have not worked from other web site, this has made a big difference.

Comment: Its the green check mark under my answer. Have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers